# Working with data on different global variables in Redux

Tags: arrays, action, redux, reducers

Imagine I need to pick a number of elements from an array of people in a global **Redux** variable and add them into another array, representing the members of a club. To do that I use a grid, which allows me to check checkboxes on the elements' corresponding rows and then click on a button to move the people to the array of members of the club.

Therefore, there are two different global variables: people, table and club (and within it the array of members). When I check every element I add the id of a person to a variable inside the table array and then when I click the button, the people with those ids are transferred to the members array inside the club variable.

This is what I intend to do:

```
people = [{id:1, name:"John"},{id:2,name:"Sandy"}]
table = {selectedIds:[]}
club = {members:[]}

//check John's checkbox
people = [{id:1, name:"John"},{id:2,name:"Sandy"}]
table = {selectedIds:[1]}
club = {members:[]}

//click the add button
people = [{id:2,name:"Sandy"}]
table = {selectedIds:[]}
club = {members:[{id:1, name:"John"}]}
```

How do I do this in Redux? What is the most appropiate way to do it? Should the reducers be mixed together? What I mean is: **is there a way to do this with just two actions**, one when selecting (which I have been able to do by myself) and another when clicking the button?

I don't want to have to dispatch a lot of actions when clicking the button to move elements from people with ids like those selected in the table to the members of the club array.

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, your question is too general and you are basically asking about how Redux works. I would recommend you watch the excellent Redux courses on egghead.io https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux   and   https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. What I don't want to have to do is to dispatch a Hell lot of actions in order to move the people with ids like those selected to the members array.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to use a single reducer that contains people, table, and club as separate arrays.

Then you would need to have actions for every event: "CHECK" and "ADD".

Then all the reducer needs to do is to listen for "CHECK" and move the corresponding Id into the table array.  It would also need to listen for "ADD" and move the corresponding Id from the table array to the club array.

You could then use selectors for every filter you need.  A common library is reselect: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no way to do this using separate reducers without having to dispatch a lot of actions when moving elements from the people array to the members of the club array? Because I need there to be three separate reducers.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Dan Abramov, Redux's creator, gave an answer to this already: https://gist.github.com/gaston23/cf6f40578524ddd085dd. Actions can be shared across reducers.